# Create term query on field contained in another field with elasticsearch-dsl-py

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using [elasticsearch-dsl-py](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-dsl-py) and would like to filter on a term that is contained inside another one like this:

```
"slug": {
    "foo": "foo-slug",
    "bar": "bar-slug "
}
```

What I do is this :

```
search.query(‘filtered’, filter={"term": {"slug.foo": "foo-slug"}})
```

I would prefer something like

```
search.filter(term, slug.foo="foo-slug")
```

But I can’t as keyword can’t include dots.

Comment: I am not a Python expert by any stretch, but can't you use the dictionary syntax from the `query`? As in `search.filter(term, {'slug.foo':'foo-slug'})`?

Answer (score 11):

If it helps anyone else, I had the same problem creating this kind of query against a child property **not** using nested objects. I found the solution was to use the `query` method instead of the `filter` method:

```
search.query('match', **{"slug.foo": "foo-slug"})
```

This worked for me in ElasticSearch 1.5.2.

Answer (score 8):

**edit... DON'T DO THIS: See aaronfay's answer for the correct approach.**

This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere which is sad...

```
>>> search.filter('term', slug__foo='foo-slug').to_dict()
{'query': {'filtered': {'filter': {'term': {u'slug.foo': 'foo-slug'}}, 'query': {'match_all': {}}}}}
```

The double underscore will be converted into dot notation. No idea if this is stable.

Comment: ohhhhh my god THX  ! The documentation is sad indeed.

Comment: arronfay's answer is the correct approach and the double underscore probably shouldn't be used as it could break in future releases.

Answer (score 0):

So I am assuming that slug is a [nested object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html) in a larger document.  In the current version (0.0.8) this can be achieved like so:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import F

...

f = F('term', foo='foo-slug')
search = search.filter('nested', path='slug', filter=f)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time after the question had been asked, but just in case anyone comes across this post, Charles's answer is actually correct, (The method shouldn't break since [it's actually mentioned in the packages docs](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#dotted-fields) now).

As the docs mention:

> ...,the Q shortcut (as well as the query, filter, and exclude methods on Search class) allows you to use __ (double underscore) in place of a dot in a keyword argument:

```
s = Search()
s = s.filter('term', category__keyword='Python')
s = s.query('match', address__city='prague')
```

It also mentions aaronfay's answer:

> Alternatively you can always fall back to python’s kwarg unpacking if
> you prefer:

```
s = Search()
s = s.filter('term', **{'category.keyword': 'Python'})
s = s.query('match', **{'address.city': 'prague'})
```

Answer (score -2):

This will do the trick for you:

```
args = {
    "slug.foo": "foo-slug"
}
search.filter(term, **args)
```