# create query on subfield (field contained in another field) using elasticsearch-dsl-py?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-dsl-py

similar to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023689/create-term-query-on-field-contained-in-another-field-with-elasticsearch-dsl-py/35182284#35182284)
I want to create a query on a sub field (which is not of type nested)

if data is in format

```
"fs": {
    "used": 1000,
    "mount_point": "/"
 }
```

as mentioned in [answer by aaronfay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35182284/4896623)
I tried querying with

```
search.query('match', **{"fs.used": 0})
```

and it works as expected.

But for field named `mount_point`, the query returns empty response.

```
search.query('match', **{"fs.mount_point": "/"})
```

even if i have data which has `mount_point = '/'`. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your mappings for the `mount_point` field? You need that field to be of type `keyword` which means without any analyzer. By default it would be `text` which means it would be split into words and `/` is not a word so it would get dropped.

Comment: thanks for the response. Its the default mapping of topbeat index created by logstash.

`mount_point` field's mapping is of type `string`

`
"fs" : {
        ...
        "mount_point" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "used" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        ...
      }
    },
`
so should i change the mapping of this field to `keyword`

Comment: solved temporarily by comparing with another field (which doesn't have only '/' in value.
`
.query('match', **{"fs.device_name": "/dev/sda4"}
`